Can any Android applications run on MIUI Pad 14?
I wonder whether any Android applications run on MIUI Pad 14 or if some Android applications won't run on it.

Unclear if you found/read: https://www.gsmarena.com/xiaomi_miui_14_android_13_walkthrough-news-58314.php

Do you have the Chinese ROM, or the Global (or EU) one?
The Chinese ROM lacks Google Mobile Services, so won't run most Play Store apps. The Global and EU ROMs have Google Mobile Services and should run most Play Store apps.
